Google Merchant Center keeps getting Missing value [image link] and Missing value [link]
I have a csv file that works for a long time without a problem in Google Merchant Center, it uploads and updates phones from the shop. I recently copied it, changed from phones to accessories but the code for getting the csv is the same other that the category. Now Google Merchant Center has a problem with the format and keeps putting everything between "". Like "https://cms.xxlgsm.hu/assets/res/galeria/113918_samsung-gy/8a08a1e64f15f71ae771d7d5eb8dba22.jpg" instead of https://cms.xxlgsm.hu/assets/res/galeria/113918_samsung-gy/8a08a1e64f15f71ae771d7d5eb8dba22.jpg like it did with the phone ones.
I checked both of the csvs and the format is the same. Anyone has any idea how should I solve this problem? Already contacted Google Help but they still didn't react after 8 days. The cvs can be dowloaded here(working) and here(not working).
If it helps this is some of the code I use:
 public function merchantCenterFeed()
    {
        // CSV adat
        $exportData = [];
        foreach ($this->getProducts() as $product) {
            $exportData[] = [
                $product['pr_id'],
                'in stock',
                $product['pr_name_hu'],
                base_url() . $this->webshop->generateHref($product),
                $this->mediaDomain . $this->getPicture($product),
                'Mobilban is a legnagyobb! Gyors házhozszállítás! Új és használt mobiltelefonok adás-vétel és szervizelés!',
                267,
                number_format($product['real_price'], 0, '.', '.') . ' HUF'
            ];
        }

        // csv format
        $header = [
            'id',
            'availability',
            'title',
            'link',
            'image_link',
            'description',
            'google_product_category',
            'price'
        ];

        // Download csv
        force_download('data.csv', generateCsv($header, $exportData, '|'), true);
    }

private function getPicture($product) {
        $picture = '';
        if ($product['gl_id']) {
            $p_data = $this->gallery->gallery_image_list($product['gl_id']);
            if ($p_data[0]['gp_file']) {
                $file = '/assets/res/galeria/' . $p_data[0]['gl_dir'] . '/' . $p_data[0]['gp_file'];
            } else {
                $file = '/assets/res/galeria/' . 'no_pic.jpg';
            }
            $picture = $file;
        } else {
            $picture = '/assets/res/galeria/' . 'no_pic.jpg';
        }

        return $picture;
    }

